# How to display row data cumulatively

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in which count of transactions completed and the duration for transactions is given group by duration.

[image]

Now I want to add transactions cumulatively eg: In duration 1 transactions are 2,in duration 2 transactions(2+4)=6, duration 5 transactions(6+3)=9.
Please suggest the method for this

Comment: Go on. Try something. If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should at least show us your expected output, which is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for `cumulative` sum but as mySQL doesn't support `ANSI OLAP` functions, so it can't be calculated the ANSI standard way.

One way around could be to use variable and keep on adding the current value to the previous sum as below.

```
set @runningSum := 0;
select duration,  
       transactions, 
       @runningSum := @runningSum + transactions AS TransRunningSum
from t1;
```

**Result:**

```
duration    transactions    TransRunningSum
-------------------------------------------
1              2                2
2              4                6
5              3                9
6              1                10
7              2                12
11             1                13
13             1                14
15             1                15
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/WOA27685)**

---

**Update 1:**

As correlated queries are supported in mySQL, you can also use it as below to achieve the same result.

```
SELECT duration
    ,transactions
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(x.transactions)
        FROM t1 x
        WHERE x.duration <= t.duration
        ) AS TransRunningSum
FROM t1 t
ORDER BY t.duration;
```

**Result:**

```
duration    transactions    TransRunningSum
-------------------------------------------
1           2               2
2           4               6
5           3               9
6           1               10
7           2               12
11          1               13
13          1               14
15          1               15
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SKXNF64835)**

Comment: Can we implement this without using a variable? I need to show these values in a view and in a view we cant use variables. Please suggest

Comment: You can also use a correlated query as shown in updated answer although it will not be as fast as variable option :-)